# Rcon Connection not timing out, even when setting manual timeout

Tags: node.js, typescript, rcon

I'm using npm i rcon-client to make rcon calls,

First I'm making a simple connection via:

```
try {
const rcon: Rcon= await Rcon.connect({host: server.address, port: server.rconPort, password: server.rconPass, timeout: 100} )
const playerList = await rcon.send(server.rconPlayerCommand)
console.log(playerList)
rcon.end()
}
catch (error) {
console.log('ERROR' + server.name)
}
```

Now if the server is online, I get a response back instantly,
However if the server is offline, it takes over a minute per server to return an error.

If I move the timeout down to something like 5ms, all requests fail (even when the server is online).

If I put the timeout at 100ms, it does not make a difference, the online servers come back almost instantly but the offline servers take over 1 minute per server.

The behaviour I'm after is that if it doesn't receive a response within 100ms, to error out so I can handle it as an 'offline' server.

I've tried changing the timeout time as per the dependency documentation, but it doesn't seem to fix the connection hanging.